# Simple substitution or elegant method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

I tried differentiating directly and plugging in the values, but that doesn't seem to yield the answer. Is there anything obvious I'm missing, or is there any shortcut to this? Please let me know the method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe making $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}$ should be enough. Do remember that this is a product, so you use the product rule to differentiate again.

Comment: Wich book is the exercise taken from?

Answer (score 2):

Chain rule:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$

Chain rule and product rule

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}\dfrac{1}{\sin x}-\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\cot x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+4y\csc^2 x=$

$=\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}\dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}-\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{1}{\sin x}+\dfrac{4y}{\sin^2 x}=0$

Finally

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}+4y=0$

<strike>You don't get the given solution.</strike>

Comment: Mistake in second line, should be (dz/dx) squared

Comment: I got the solution, it matches, thankss

Comment: I forgot that the chain rule is applied always. Sorry.